# Library MAY need to reference the application using it? C#

Tags: c#, reference

Sorry for dodgy title, couldn't think of anything better...

Anyway, I have written a library for the viewing of a system basically. This library is used by the editor application of the system. Unfortunately, i got hit by the sudden need for the library to have a variable in one of its classes to access the editing application. Of course this isn't possible without a reference. The thing is, i feel it is unnecessary to reference the editor application when out of the hundreds of times this library may be used, only one of the applications using it (the editor), will mean the library needs to have the editor referenced to it.

I really hope that made sense.

In most cases : Application uses Library
In editor case: Editor uses Library uses Editor

I basically want a way around having to reference the editor from the library. All my requirements is for a variable of type (or a loop hole to access) MyClass (default value null) to be stored in the library. MyClass is part of the editor though, not the library, and i DO NOT want to have to reference the editor.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not necessary. Please explain, why the library needs access to `MyClass`, so we can find a better way to do this. Most likely it will be an event that your library provides onto which the editor can subscribe itself and carry out whatever you currently want to do inside the library.

Comment: I had the same problem when I was developing a library to be used in both WPF and WinForm application. If you are using editor feature and can't avoid it at all cost then u may have to reference it in. But you should develop as loosly coupled approach as you may. Please post some code to see

Comment: Thanks Daniel, basically i wanted the library to check some things, but passing all the variables from the editor to the library would have been a huge amount of work :/

usr's answer seems like it should work though, ill try it out now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an interface which you "Editor" implements. The library does not need to know the concrete implementation, it can work with the interface.

Comment: And put the Interface into its own assembly, so the Library references the Interface's assembly, and not the Editor assembly. The Editor assembly will also need to reference the Interface assembly.